# mysql utf8mb4_unicode_ci cause unique key collision

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `mb1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I insert tow rows

```
insert into mb1(name) values('K'),('Ｋ');
```

Note, the second K is unicode character

```
+------+-----------+
| name | hex(name) |
+------+-----------+
| K    | 4B        |
| Ｋ   | EFBCAB    |
+------+-----------+
```

Why do they cause unique key collision? Aren't they different character in utf8mb4?

After remove COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, the problem disappeared.

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do they cause unique key collision? Aren't they different character in utf8mb4?

You are missing the point about `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`.  A `CHARACTER SET` is a collection of different characters.  A `COLLATION` says whether to treat the characters as equal -- think `A` and `a` -- different characters, but treated for `ORDER BY` and `WHERE =`, etc as being the same.

```
mysql> SELECT 'K'='Ｋ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+-----------------------------------+
| 'K'='Ｋ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So in utf8_unicode_ci (or utf8mb4_unicode_ci), those two characters are considered to be "equal".

"Equal" is the test for `UNIQUE` keys.

Set the `COLLATION` for the column to whatever makes sense for you.

- **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** for good 'real life' comparisons, apparently including this one.  K=k=Ķ=ķ
- **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** for more simple-minded comparisons.  In particular no 2-character combinations match 1-character encodings.  Case folding and accent stripping does occur.  K=k=Ķ=ķ
- **utf8mb4_bin** blindly checks the bits.  No case folding, etc.  K k Ķ ķ are all unequal.

utf8mb4_latvian_ci is a little different: K=k but not equal to Ķ=ķ .  There are other specialized collations for other languages (mostly Western European).

Your `Ｋ` is called "FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K", so it is quite reasonable that it compare equal to Latin `K`.