# Emojis as question marks in MariaDB primary key

Tags: unicode, sqlalchemy, mariadb, primary-key, emoji

With the following table, using mariadb-server-10.1               10.1.32+maria-1~trusty:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `tag_name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `thing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`thing_id`,`tag_name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Manifests as (in SQLAlchemy app):

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) 
(1062, "Duplicate entry '1532-?' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

at the second emoji insertion attempt.

The first one seems to be ok in the db (believe me, it shows right in my console and my browser as "alien" emoji):

```
> select tag_name, HEX(tag_name) from tags;
+----------+----------------+
| tag_name | HEX(tag_name)  |
+----------+----------------+
| GOODGUY  | 474F4F44475559 |
|         | F09F91BD       |
+----------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am aware of [Emoji's in mysql turns to question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385862/emojis-in-mysql-turns-to-question-marks) , but  my.cnf has:

```
default-character-set = utf8mb4
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

and utf8mb4 is being used in the client (charset added to connection string as `?charset=utf8mb4`). And I believe primary key is checked on the server side.

Is there anything else I am missing (can check) or is it some MariaDB bug or some additional configuration required?

not sure whether relevant or not, but the same problem when inserting via `mysql` shell. Also tried this to see what is going on (found this in [mysql utf8mb4_unicode_ci cause unique key collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867895/mysql-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-cause-unique-key-collision) ):

```
> SELECT ''='' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
+------------------------------------+
| '?'='?' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
```

but not sure whether this relevant.

I do not understand: database sometimes shows it alright (via both clients - shell and SQLAlchemy app), but then fails to show in the header? From the evidence I got, I do not understand where that bad conversion happens. The data seems to be ok in the database (see hex above), but two emojis equivalent for the primary key?

One more to contrast:

```
> SELECT ''='' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
+-----------------------------+
| '?'='?' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
```

This kind of points finger primary key does not use binary? All emojis converted to something else before being used in the index? Quite weird.

Comment: See question marks in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: @RickJames please, do not jump to conclusions so quickly. The question you refer to does not solve my problem. I am already using techniques described there.

Comment: Could it be that #1532 is already tagged with that Emoji?  And you are `INSERTing` the same tag again?  And the 'question mark' is actually coming from SQLAlchemy, not MySQL?  If so, consider `INSERT IGNORE ...`.

Comment: Its the same via mysql shell. I found another collation-related answer, but it's not definite what to do. Will update answer in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT ''='' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
+----------------------------------------+
| '?'='?' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Two things to note:

- The *520* collation treats them as different.
- The question marks are a display problem.

To further isolate that...

```
mysql> SELECT HEX('');
+----------+
| HEX('?') |
+----------+
| F09F9886 |
+----------+
```

My point is that the question mark may be a *display* problem, and (as you point out with the hex) it is not an encoding problem:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry '1532-?' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

And, if you want to tag 1532 with both Emoji, that column needs to be `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (or utf8mb4_bin).

Comment: Yes, I have the same results as above. But what is that `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` ? Why should I choose it over my current choice? I see a lot of posts how to get rid of that "520".

Comment: Ok. found description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904883/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8-unicode-ci-and-utf8-unicode-520-ci

Comment: @RomanSusi - The 520 treats Emoji as distinct.  That link is talking about Turkish.  520 does not deal as well with Language-specific requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385099/1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-520-ci , plus more by googling - I have not read any further. Of course, there are similarly misguided advices to replace utf8mb4 with utf8

Comment: @RomanSusi - And the second link dealt with someone downgrading from 5.6 (which has 520) to 5.5.  Again, a valid reason for avoiding 520, but not a reason that applies for you.

Comment: Maybe I was not paying that much attention to versions there, but before switching to another collation at least I need to know what else will happen. The system uses more collations / character than emoji and ASCII. However, I must accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: It may be that 520 did not exist in your version 10.1.10?  Or is that 10.1.32?

Comment: It's 10.1.32 - it is there.